# =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(TEXTSPLIT(B2,," "),TEXTSPLIT(A2," ")))),"Match","No Match") Text string match in excel

Tags: excel, string, text, excel-formula, match

I want a formula to compare 2 cells to see even if one word is present in another. Below are my examples, please help me to figure one formula that can work across all these cells. I need each of these examples to match or is there a way I can highlight the words of column B in column A. Thank you.

[image]

Formula I used

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(TEXTSPLIT(B2,," "),TEXTSPLIT(A2," ")))),"Match","No Match")
```

Comment: Please add you examples as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that XMATCH looks for full match, but wildcard can be used
Try this (not checked)

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(XMATCH("*"&TEXTSPLIT(B2,," ")&"*",TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),2))),"Match","No Match")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(ISERR(SEARCH(TEXTSPLIT(B2," "),A2))),"No ",)&"Match"
```

Comment: What does this formula mean? Please elaborate.